# How to configure vsftpd and iptables to listen on port 21 but run on another port?

Tags: iptables, ftp, port, forwarding, vsftpd

We have a Java process which contains an embedded FTP server which I'd like to run on a RHEL5 machine.  I don't want to run the process as root and I don't want clients to have to specify a port when making a connection.  It seems like I should be able to configure vsftpd to listen on an alternative port (e.g. 20000) and then configure ipchains to forward all traffic on port 21 to 20000.  I think specifically I need to:

1. Configure vsftpd to listen on port 20000
2. Configure `ip_conntrack_ftp` to forward traffic from port 21 to 20000

So my initial question is does this seem like a reasonable approach?

To accomplish step 1 I've modified my vsftpd.conf to have the following line:

```
listen_port=20000
```

I can then restart vsftpd and verify it is listening on 20000 by doing the following:

```
> ftp tstweb1 20000
Connected to tstweb1.pulseenergy.com.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
Name (tstweb1:cclark):
```

And I proceed to login without issue.  Step 1 complete.

As for step 2, I don't see the module loaded:

```
> /sbin/lsmod | grep ftp

>
```

So I try to load it with the proper port forwarding information:

```
> /sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp ports=21,20000
```

And I verify it has loaded:

```
> /sbin/lsmod | grep ftp
ip_conntrack_ftp       41489  0 
ip_conntrack           91109  3 ip_conntrack_ftp,iptable_nat,ip_nat
```

But I get a connection refused when I try to use it:

```
> ftp tstweb1
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

I know FTP is a complex protocol with active and passive modes and communication on multiple ports but I was under the impression the `ip_conntrack_ftp` module would hide a lot of that for me.  Do I need to write some specific iptables rules in addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is REDIRECT:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -j REDIRECT --to-port 20000
```

And you need to use passive-ftp.